# printing different size of text than is on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I'm using JS to print a page.
Can anyone tell me why no matter what size the text is on screen, large or small, it prints the the same size of text all the time which is around 10px...

```
<a id="printPageButton" onclick="printPage();">         
<button>Print</button>
</a> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function printPage() {
    //Get the print button and put it into a variable
    var printButton = document.getElementById("printPageButton");
    //Set the print button visibility to 'hidden' 
    printButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    //Print the page content
    window.print()
    //Set the print button to 'visible' again 
    //[Delete this line if you want it to stay hidden after printing]
    printButton.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
</script>
```

thanks

Comment: Are you styling the text through a stylesheet that is set to media="screen"?

Comment: does your style sheet say your text should be 10px?

Comment: Why don't you use `CSS` with `@media print`?

Comment: no my text size is set to 16 px....No there is no reference to media="screen i my ss

Comment: ok il give the @media a go thanks